# python NameError: name 'file' is not defined

Tags: python, pip, gunicorn

I dont know much about python. I want to start working on the project and the setup instruction says:

```
pip install -r requirements-dev.txt
```

Simple enougth. The problem is that I get this:

```
    Downloading/unpacking gunicorn==0.13.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 7))
  Running setup.py egg_info for package gunicorn
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-root/gunicorn/setup.py", line 18, in <module>
        long_description = file(
    NameError: name 'file' is not defined
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>

  File "/tmp/pip-build-root/gunicorn/setup.py", line 18, in <module>

    long_description = file(

NameError: name 'file' is not defined
```

I dont understand the problem. Maybe somebody can help out?

I run this on Arch Linux, python defaults to python 3 and the project is not python 3 but I'm not sure if that's it.

Answer (score 194):

**`file()` is not supported in Python 3**

Use `open()` instead; see [Built-in Functions - open()](https://docs.python.org/release/3.0/library/functions.html#open).

Answer (score 9):

It seems that your project is written in Python < 3. This is because the [`file()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#file) builtin function [is removed in Python 3](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins). Try using Python [2to3 tool](http://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html) or [edit the erroneous file yourself](http://docs.python.org/dev/howto/pyporting.html).

The [project page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gunicorn/) clearly mentions that

> Gunicorn requires Python 2.x >= 2.5. **Python 3.x support is planned.**

Comment: For someone who claims he's not familiar with Python I think it might be a bad idea to try to port Gunicorn to Python 3 :). It's just not going to work, using Python 2.7 is the better option here.

Comment: My bad! I missed those words... Sorry :(

Comment: do you know the exact fix which converts from file to open in 2to3? I was looking for it, but according to the documentation it seems that this part needs to be changed manually because it is not implemented :(

Answer (score 5):

file is not defined in Python3, which you are using apparently. The package you're instaling is not suitable for Python 3, instead, you should install Python 2.7 and try again.

See: http://docs.python.org/release/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins

Comment: (if OP really uses Python 3.x) Gunicorn 0.13.4 requires Python 2.x >= 2.5. Source: "Installation" section at: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gunicorn/0.13.4

Answer (score 1):

Search the function `file()` on your entire code, and replace it with `open()`.

Answer (score -3):

To solve this error, it is enough to add `from google.colab import files`
in your code!