# python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1，NameError: name 'file' is not defined

Tags: python, django, installation

I am beginner. I am trying to install pybars module.
But the error code is

C:\TarTool>pip install pybars
You are using pip version 6.0.8, however version 6.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Collecting pybars
  Using cached pybars-0.0.4.tar.gz
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "", line 20, in 
      File "C:\Users\bwang\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-zubm22_7\pybars\setup.py
", line 22, in 
        description = file(
    NameError: name 'file' is not defined
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "<string>", line 20, in <module>

  File "C:\Users\bwang\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-zubm22_7\pybars\setup.py
```

", line 22, in

```
    description = file(

NameError: name 'file' is not defined

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\bwan
```

g\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-zubm22_7\pybars

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736833/python-nameerror-name-file-is-not-defined

Comment: I am using python 3.4

Comment: Yes, and it seems you want to install a package that is not compatible with Python 3.X Either go back to Python 2, use another package or fork and update pybars so it works with Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I uninstalled Python 3.4 and installed Python 2.7, then lending club installation succeeded. But I am surprised about the new version, which should be compatible to the old version.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python3, try the following to install the compatible version of pybars

```
pip install pybars3
```